Add and Remove classList between two buttons
I have two buttons inside my video projects, "Pause" and "Play" and looking for a special color effect to be applied on the current active button only, but clicking the current button couldn't remove the color effect on the button which was clicked before.
The target is for the special color effect to be applied interchangeably. What line of code did I miss here?


const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".switch-btn");

btns.forEach((btn) => {
      btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        const currentBtn = event.currentTarget;

        if (!currentBtn.classList.contains("active")) {
          currentBtn.classList.add("active")
        } else {
          currentBtn.classList.remove("active")
        }

      })
<div class="btns">
  <button class="switch-btn" data-control="pause">Pause</button>
  <button class="switch-btn" data-control="play"> Play</button>
</div>




Please revise the snippet posted as it currently contains syntax errors. Is this a copy/paste error or your actual code?

On a button being clicked, go through the other button(s) and clear their active state. However, have you considered looking into radio buttons (or even just having one button?).

First, remove the 'active' class from all buttons, Then add the 'active' class only to the clicked button.

@DeveloperNilesh that would seem logical, but it's not what the OP appears to want to happen as each button seems to be being used as a toggle button (ie both can be 'off' at the same time - though I'm not sure what state that would leave the playing in).

There's missing brackets at the end of .forEach(). (Hint: }); )

First, remove the 'active' class from all buttons, Then add the 'active' class only to the clicked button, Just add the HTML, CSS and JS sequencing as per your HTML code:


const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".switch-btn");

btns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    btns.forEach(button => {
      button.classList.remove("active");
    });

    event.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
  });
});
.switch-btn {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-btn.active {
  background-color: #f5c453;
  color: white;
}
<div class="btns">
  <button class="switch-btn" data-control="pause">Pause</button>
  <button class="switch-btn" data-control="play">Play</button>
</div>




Please remove the comment-answers you posted above which duplicate this solution. They shouldn't be posted in the first place.



const btns = document.querySelectorAll(".switch-btn");

document.querySelector("#btnPause").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  btns.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove("btn-active"));
  e.target.classList.add("btn-active");
});

document.querySelector("#btnPlay").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  btns.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove("btn-active"));
  e.target.classList.add("btn-active");
});
.switch-btn {
  background: #CCC;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  color: #000;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-btn:hover,
.btn-active {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #00F;
}
<div class="btns">
  <button class="switch-btn" data-control="pause" id="btnPause">Pause</button>
  <button class="switch-btn" data-control="play" id="btnPlay">Play</button>
</div>




Literally the same as the first answer.

Duplicate answer is given.

Yes. I saw that coming.  The difference is that event.currentTarget and e.target.
Anyway, if it will be given one more downvote will take it down. Thanks.

I have updated my code.
